# Flutter Stop the letter sound when moving to another letter

Tags: flutter, audio, overlapping

**In case the user did not wait to hear
the sound of the letter
He moved between the buttons quickly
There is an overlap between the voices,
and all the voices remain .
in the background of the application
How to correct or solve the problem?**
full code

https://github.com/Saleque474/Learn-Alphabet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBiHR.png)

`dependencies  : kplayer: ^0.2.4`

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String currentAlphabet = "A";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber[200],
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        var height = constraints.maxHeight;
        var width = constraints.maxWidth;
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            sentenceHolder(height, width),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                imageHolder(height, width),
                wordHolder(height, width),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              child: Wrap(
                children: changePos(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  playAudio(String path) {
    Player.asset(path).play();
  }

  List<Widget> changePos() {
    List<Widget> children = [
      ...alphabets
          .map(
            (e) => textHolder(e),
          )
          .toList()
    ];

    return children;
  }
```

```
Widget textHolder(String alphabet) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          currentAlphabet = alphabet;
          playAudio("assets/audio/$alphabet.wav");
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Text(alphabet),
      ),
    );
  }
```

//
When calling a letter sound is a function

It works normally, but if we move quickly between the letter buttons, we notice that all the sounds work together at the same time
//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // _audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _playAudio(String assetPath) async {
    _audioPlayer.pause();
    assetPath = ("assets/audio/$currentAlphabet.mp3");
    try {
      await _audioPlayer.setAsset(assetPath);
      _audioPlayer.play();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error loading audio source: $e");
    }
  }}
```

i solved  by using  just_audio:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Kja.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YmkG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q83mr.png)

Answer (score 0):

One Simple solution is:
stop the already playing song/sound before calling play()

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this case by following 3 steps:

1- Create a public object from the player class(nullable)
Make sure to declare it outside the method playAudio;
Player? publicPlayer;

2- before playing the sound make sure to stop the old sound

if(publicPlayer != null) publicPlayer.stop();

3- instead of calling Player.asset(path).play();
call after assigning the publicPlayer;

publicPlayer = Player.asset(path);
publicPlayer.play();

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OZG63KmVtvv3UfqqOflXgLK32OH1SSTa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SqtFV8eKMtfXfBwbp5oKhkcXcatHPaiP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you call the method without () .stop(); not .stop;

Comment: itest  all  but not working   for  now                im using  this  solution
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YJ-dXxtpLVWuY1M2kpzriHwhQbCHUDt1/view?usp=sharing